# Java : Pass updated json as input to post rest api

Tags: java, json

I am new to Java and Rest assured API. My requirement is , i have to update received json response and again have call same API with updated response as input content to that api

```
Response response = Seller.postSeller(environmentURI, someinput);
               String responseString = response.asString();

        JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
                JSONArray dataArray = responseObject.getJSONObject("data");

        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                       responseObject.put("currentDate", SystemDate.getTodaysDate());
                       }


                       //Again I have to call this API

                       Response response = Seller.postSeller(environmentURI, someinput); 
                       //Here I have update "currentDate": "2019-02-23" to todays date and have to pass that as someinput string
```

Received Response:

```
{ data:[ 
                   {"Id": "1",
                   "Number": "G24101457",
                    "oldDate": "2016-01-01",
                    "currentDate": "2019-02-23"
                    },
                    {"Id": "2",
                   "Number": "G24101457",
                    "oldDate": "2016-01-01",
                    "currentDate": "2019-02-23"
                    }
                    ]
                    }
```

Basically my requirement is to update json and pass to the post request as body

Comment: You're posting requirements, code and some JSON, but as of yet, no clear or focused question. Please help us by fixing this. The [ask] link can help.

Comment: Why are changing `currentDate` field in `responseObject`? Instead, you have to put in `jsonObject` inside the for loop.

Comment: See i am calling post method to update existing created resource. In our case developer have implemented put as post so whenever we want to call any put , we call post. And that api is taking similar json as input. So when i will call post first time then it will keep some currentdate as provided in input json. Now i want to call that post api again like put and have to pass same json by updating currentdate

Comment: Understood that you need to call the `POST` API with updated `currentDate` value in the previously received response. See my answer carefully. It exactly does that, updates `currentDate` in the previously received `responseObject`. Now, call the POST API by passing `responseObject.toString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mistakenly changing `currentDate` field in `responseObject`. You have to modify `jsonObject` inside the for loop.

```
jsonObject.put("currentDate", new Date());
```

There was a small mistake in getting the data array, it is supposed to be:

```
JSONArray dataArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("data");
```

Call the API using the same `responseObject`:

```
Response response = Seller.postSeller(environmentURI, responseObject.toString());
```

Note: The date I am putting in `currentdate` field as `new Date()` is just an example, you may put the date in your required format.

Here is the running sample:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;

public class ModifyResponse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Response response = Seller.postSeller(environmentURI, someinput);
        //String responseString = response.asString();
        String responseString = "{ 'data': [{ 'Id': '1', 'Number': 'G24101457', 'oldDate': '2016-01-01', 'currentDate': '2019-02-23' }, { 'Id': '2', 'Number': 'G24101457', 'oldDate': '2016-01-01', 'currentDate': '2019-02-23' } ] }";
        JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
        JSONArray dataArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("data");

        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
            //Here I have update "currentDate": "2019-02-23" to todays date and have to pass that as someinput string
            jsonObject.put("currentDate", new Date());
        }

        System.out.println("Modified data: " + responseObject);
        //Again I have to call this API
        //Response response = Seller.postSeller(environmentURI, responseObject.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: See when i will call post first time it will return some json. What i have to do is - i have to make again one more post request just updating date. Why i am updating date from response , the reason is when i call update api in our case post api , it takes same json body as input and i have to just change date from that response body

Comment: Lets consider this better way - I have responseString in json format and i have to update that json string by updating date feild inside that and have to call post api again by passing that json as input

Comment: @simond the above code shared does exactly what you need. 1. You call the first API and get 'responseString`. 2. Then parse this `responseString` and assign to `responseObject`. 3. From `responseObject` you get the `data` array. 4. Iterate this `data` array and for each `jsonObject` inside the `data` array, update the `currentDate`. The `responseObject` changes automatically. So, you effectively change the `repsonseObject` through `jsonObject` it contains. 5. Finally, convert the `responseObject` to `String` (`JSON` format) and use it to call the next API. Please run the shared code.

Comment: @simond glad to know that it's working for you. Would you please accept the answer?